# How can I define selection using [] for a new class?

Tags: python

I've created a new class and I'd like to define how to  use [] to select things from it.  Is there a way to do that?

```
class NewClass:
    def __init__(self, list):
        self.list_item = list

    # def __indexer__(self, slice_object):
    #     return list[slice_object]

example = NewClass(range(0, 5))
print example[0:3]
```

Comment: Have a look at this section of the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it's called [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).

```
class NewClass(object):
    def __init__(self, list):
        self.list_item = list
    def __getitem__(self, slice_object):
        return self.list_item[slice_object]

example = NewClass(range(0, 5))
print(example[0:3])
```